# PayPal code works until I add prices for options?

Tags: html, forms, paypal

Not sure what to ask exactly but I've followed the instructions on the PayPal Developer site:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/

have another question though. I have a form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@myaddress.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="MR_BuyNow_WPS_CA">
    <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='CA'>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="/design/payments/success/">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="/design/payments/failed/">
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to MR">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="buy-time">
    <table>
        <tr><td>
            <p>Provide the following:</p>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <span class="prefix"><span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="Please provide your full name as it appears on the order form.">Name:</span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="small-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="What is your name?" name="os0" maxlength="200">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-12 columns">
                    <select name="item_name">
                        <option value="Maintenance Hours">Maintenance</option>
                        <option value="General Work Hours">General Work (Additions, etc.)</option>
                    </select> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-12 columns">
                    <select name="os1">
                        <option value="2 Hours ($50/Hour)">2 Hours ($50/Hour) - $100.00 CAD</option>
                        <option value="3 Hours ($45/Hour)">3 Hours ($45/Hour) - $135.00 CAD</option>
                        <option value="4 Hours ($45/Hour)">4 Hours ($45/Hour) - $180.00 CAD</option>
                        <option value="5 Hours ($45/Hour)">5 Hours ($45/Hour) - $225.00 CAD</option>
                        <option value="6 Hours ($45/Hour)">6 Hours ($45/Hour) - $270.00 CAD</option>
                    </select> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </td></tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Client">
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Hours">
    <input type="image" class="payments-buy" src="http://mrobertsdesign.ca/img/payments_buy.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

Now it technically works (it at least goes through to the paypal purchase page) until I actually add the prices for the buttons:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="2 Hours">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="100.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="3 Hours">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="135.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="4 Hours">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="180.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="5 Hours">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="225.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select4" value="6 Hours">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount4" value="270.00">
```

If anyone with any experience could point out something I'm missing that would be great =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the value of `ABC` in `<option value="A">`, `<input type="hidden" name="option_selectX" value="B">`, and `<input type="hidden" name="option_amountX" value="C">` must (1) not contain any capitals, special characters or spaces, (2) it also must either be alphanumeric or contain at least one letter, and (3) be one whole phrase:

Accepted:

```
1plug
thisisananswer
5000b
```

Not accepted for me:

```
1
1 plug
5000
this is an answer
```

This is strange to me because the value of `<option value="A">` could include spaces before I included `<input type="hidden" name="option_selectX" value="B">` and `<input type="hidden" name="option_amountX" value="C">`.

Took me a little while of trial and error to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, but would it be easier to use PayPal's built in use of dropdowns for a button? Since you are basically saying that the hourly rate is discounted you could use a buy now button that is set for $50 and if they choose a quantity of 3 or more it is discounted to $45. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually you did help a lot, that's a great idea... I want to set a limit though, I don't want someone being able to buy my life lol, but I don't want to use their built in features if it can be done this way, if I change paypal accounts it's much less hassle